# OpenCL: Call parameter type does not match function signature

Tags: opencl

I'm using `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp16 : enable` supported GPU with OpenCL 1.2. I wanted to check the performance improvement by changin float precision from 32 to 16. In my device kernel, I converted all `float` to `half` like shown below:

```
__kernel void copy_kernel(int N,  __global half *X, __global half *Y)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    if(i < N) Y[i] = X[i];
}
```

In my host side, I made `cl_mem` point to array of `cl_half`. Host program looks as shown below:

```
void copy(int N, cl_mem X, cl_mem Y)
{
    cl_kernel kernel = get_copy_kernel();
    cl_command_queue queue = cl.queue;

    cl_uint i = 0;

    cl.error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, i++, sizeof(N), (void*) &N);
    cl.error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, i++, sizeof(X), (void*) &X);
    cl.error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, i++, sizeof(Y), (void*) &Y);
    check_error_cl(cl);

    size_t gsize = N;
    cl.error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, 0, &gsize, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
    check_error_cl(cl);
}
```

But while compiling the kernel, I get the below error:

```
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
  %32 = load half addrspace(1)* %31, align 2
 float  %33 = call float @llvm.nvvm.mul.rn.f(half %32, half %19)
Broken module found, compilation terminated!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a half variable to the kernel but the kernel expects a pointer to an array of halfs.

If you want to pass an array of halfs to the GPU you still have to use cl_mem objects which then contains the array of halfs.

Comment: I changed X & Y back to cl_mem. I'm passing &X to the kernel function which points to an array of cl_half's. But still the same error.

Comment: And if you change halfs to floats it works correctly?

Comment: It works when I change half to float. When I try with half datatype in device code in another GPU, I'm getting Error number -52 (CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS).